# How to change pitch of camera in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a TB3 simulation in Gazebo as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgOvX3rUsI4

I want to change the pitch of the camera on TB3 to look lower, so that TB3 still can see the ball even it is very close.

But which file and parameter should I change?
.urdf.xacro? .gazebo.xacro? model.config? model.sdf?

There are many files with similar setting that confusing me...

Please advise, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290616/how-to-change-pitch-of-camera-in-gazebo?/) by [KrizChong](https://answers.ros.org/users/18798/krizchong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-08**:
can you share referred GitHub link for better understanding?

**Comment by [KrizChong](https://answers.ros.org/users/18798/krizchong/) on 2018-05-08**:
The robot description are in https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.
The simulation models are from https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.
The model I use is waffle_pi

**Comment by [KrizChong](https://answers.ros.org/users/18798/krizchong/) on 2018-05-08**:
I did edit turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_waffle_pi.gazebo.xacro,
when I change the FOV of Pi camera, it show the view of camera is changed,
but when I change the pose of Pi camera, nothing change on the view of camera...

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-05-08**:
In the same file mention above, you will find in the camera sensor pose as `<pose>0.003 0.011 0.008 0 0 0</pose>`.
This pose actually has 6 elements  `x,y,z,r,p,y`. This r,p,y stand for roll pitch and yaw. by changing these parameters you can change the roll pitch and yaw of joint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is some of my urdf.xacro file that impliments a camera at a specified camera_pitch. Note line 11:

```
<!-- Vision Camera -->
    <link name="camera_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <box size="${camera_size} ${camera_size} ${camera_size}" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    </link>
    <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 ${1+base_height}" rpy="0 ${-cam_pitch} 0" />
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="camera_link" />
    </joint>
    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
      <sensor type="camera" name="camera">
        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <camera name="head">
          <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>752</width>
            <height>480</height>
            <format>L8</format>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.02</near>
            <far>300</far>
          </clip>
          <!--noise>
            <type>gaussian</type>
            < Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
                 That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
                 channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. >
            <mean>0.0</mean>
            <stddev>0.007</stddev>
          </noise-->
        </camera>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
          <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
          <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
          <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
          <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
          <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
          <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
          <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
          <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
          <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [cmfuhrman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33793/cmfuhrman/) with karma: 200 on 2018-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KrizChong](https://answers.ros.org/users/18798/krizchong/) on 2018-05-09**:
Sorry for late reply, I tried it just now, it works! thank you very much!!!